# PowerShell V5 Invoke-RestMethod arrays sent as System.Object[]

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, scripting

I am using Layer2 Cloud Connector as a data integration service. The software has a local based REST API which can be invoked by PowerShell scripts. I am trying to create a script which will post a new connection to the service using Invoke-RestMethod, which is shown in the [documentation](https://www.layer2solutions.com/docs/default-source/technical/documentation/layer2-cloud-connector-user-documentation.pdf). My POST call is successful, but the arrays in my post are being sent as System.Object[].

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

When I run the code below, the call is successful at creating the connection, but anything that is passed as an array shows up as System.Object[].

```
$body = @{
    name        = "Sites Test"
    consecutiveErrors     = 0
    initialOverwrite      = $True
    direction             = "LeftToRight"
    schedule              = @{
        enabled  = $False
        interval = 10
        start    = "2019-02-14T06:19:45.3892419-07:00"
    }
    leftEntity  = @{
        name                  = "left"
        providerInvariantName = "Layer2.LaCuaba.JSON"
        connectionString      = "Uri=https://example.url;"
        selectStatement       = "SELECT * from JSONData"
        primaryKey            = "code"
        encryptions           = @()
        deletionProtectionThreshhold = 30
    }
    rightEntity = @{
        name                  = "right"
        providerInvariantName = "Layer2.SharePoint.Provider"
        connectionString      = "Url=https://example.url;"
        selectStatement       = "SELECT * from JSONData"
        primaryKey            = ""
        operation             = @(
            "Read",
            "Delete",
            "Insert",
            "Update"
        )
        encryptions           = ((
            "ConnectionString"
        ) -join ",")
        deletionProtectionThreshhold = 30
    }
    mapping = @{
        auto                  = $False
        entries               = @(
            @{
                left = "code"
                right = "Title"
            },
            @{
                left = "description"
                right = "Description"
            },
            @{
                left = "alternateId"
                right = "RandomNumber"
            }
        )
    }
    conflictResolution = @{
        name = "FailAndAbort"
        entity = ""
    }
}
$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:[port]/v1/connections" -Method Post -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json"
```

Based on all of the other Invoke-RestMethod issues I've read, the '-ContentType "application/json"' should solve the issue I'm having, but the output is still showing System.Object[]. Here is an example of the output:

```
name               : Sites Test
consecutiveErrors  : 0
initialOverwrite   : True
direction          : LeftToRight
schedule           : @{enabled=False; interval=10; start=2019-02-14T06:19:45.3892419-07:00}
leftEntity         : @{name=left; providerInvariantName=Layer2.LaCuaba.JSON; connectionString=Uri=https://example.url;; 
                     selectStatement=SELECT * from JSONData; primaryKey=code; replicationKey=; generateId=False; operations=System.Object[]; 
                     encryptions=System.Object[]; dynamicColumns=System.Object[]; deletionProtectionThreshold=0}
rightEntity        : @{name=right; providerInvariantName=Layer2.SharePoint.Provider; 
                     connectionString=Url=https://example.url; 
                     selectStatement=SELECT * from JSONData; primaryKey=; replicationKey=; generateId=False; operations=System.Object[]; encryptions=System.Object[]; 
                     dynamicColumns=System.Object[]; deletionProtectionThreshold=0}
mapping            : @{auto=False; entries=System.Object[]}
conflictResolution : @{name=FailAndAbort; entity=}
error              :
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is an issue of JSON conversion depth. The `-Depth` parameter of `ConvertTo-Json` defaults to a paltry 2 I think, so try it with a sufficiently high number (10?) and I think that will do it.

---

Turns out this was a case of the way the output is formatted on the screen. Assigning the result to a variable like `$result` and then looking at `$result.mapping.entries` for example should show that the real values actually exist.

Comment: I did forget about the default depth. However, that did not fix the issue. I changed it to 10 and then 100, with the same result of System.Object[]. Thinking more into it, it looks like the other types are being read at the same depth as the arrays, but only the arrays output this issue.

Comment: @wrradez in that case this might be a case of just the way the output is formatted on the screen. Assign the result to a variable `$result` and then look at `$result.mapping.entries` for instance. Is it actually ok then?

Comment: that was it! Thank you for your help! I will mark this as the answer

Comment: @wrradez glad that helped, I edited the actual explanation into the answer.